# root device not found. Skipping fsck

Tags: arch-linux, dual-boot, lvm, systemd-boot

I dual-boot windows and arch on my work laptop on a single disk with lvm and a XBOOTLDR partition. I  use systemd-boot as a bootloader. It worked fine for like 3 months and then suddenly, after several updates, can't boot as it shows the following message:

```
:: running hook [keymap]
:: loading keymap ... done.
Waiting 10 seconds for device '<root_device>' ...
[    7.234501] hid-generic 0003:0E8D:20FF:0001: No inputs registered, leaving
ERROR: device '<root_device>' not found. Skipping fsck.
:: mounting '<root_device>' on real root
mount: /new_root: no filesystem type specified.
You are now being dropped into an emergency shell.
sh: can't access tty: job control turned off
[rootfs ]#
```

Following are the outputs of :

#### lsblk

```
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda                     8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1                  8:1    0   100M  0 part /efi  <-- existing Windows efi system partition
├─sda2                  8:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda3                  8:3    0 458.2G  0 part       <-- C:
├─sda4                  8:4    0 261.1G  0 part       <-- resized D:
├─sda5                  8:5    0   500M  0 part /boot <-- XBOOTLDR partition
└─sda6                  8:6    0 211.6G  0 part 
  ├─volgroup0-lv_root 254:1    0    30G  0 lvm  /
  └─volgroup0-lv_home 254:2    0 181.6G  0 lvm  /home
```

#### cat /etc/fstab

```
# /dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_root

UUID=f0480644-7a7c-42fe-a129-9de278563336   /           ext4        rw,relatime 0 1

# /dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_home

UUID=5080944b-07bc-4e29-8295-27ea557720a0   /home       ext4        rw,relatime 0 2

# /dev/sda1

UUID=ECCF-B1A8          /efi        vfat        rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro   0 2

# /dev/sda5

UUID=80E6-2B1C          /boot       vfat        rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro   0 2
```

#### cat /boot/loader/entries/arch.conf

```
title   Arch Linux
linux   /vmlinuz-linux
initrd  /initramfs-linux.img
options root=UUID=f0480644-7a7c-42fe-a129-9de278563336 rw
```

I install the bootloader with this command:

`# bootctl install --esp-path=/efi --boot-path=/boot`

Can't find what I am doing wrong with this setup.
Thanks for your help.

I tried to chroot into the system and reinstall the kernel and systemd-boot or change the `arch.conf` file to point to the root device with labels or name but none worked

Comment: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/77780 I don’t trust Chance.